# How to unlock a file and delete it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a program that uploads files to a ftp server. If upload is complete then I delete the files. Occasionally the files are not deleted and because the upload is automated I get an infinite loop where 100 copies of the file reach the server. If I try to manually delete the file from explorer I'm able to do it but for some reason the Deletefile command from my app doesn't work.

I've tried raising last OSError and I get nothing.

The files are stored on a mapped drive. Is there any workaround? If I upload 30 files to a ftp server sometimes one or two files cannot be deleted after loading them to the server.

Is there any way to close the file even if it is opened from another program? Something like unlocker does?

How can i see if my application is locking the file? I haven't implemented any locking mechanism inside the app.

Thanks.

Comment: That suggests ftp has finished with the file, but the os on the machine serving the files hasn't. Put a delay in between the upload and the delete. DeleteFile returns true false, are you testing for that?

Comment: DeleteFile returns false only for those files that the app is unable to delete. For the rest of the files that were deleted it returns true.

Comment: Well yes, obviously are you testing if deletefile worked in your code. e.g. while(!DeleteFile(someFile) do sleep(500);. PS a retry count and quite might be good as well.

Comment: I haven't tried this approach.Thanks for the tip. I'll give it a try. I thought the OS would execute the delete command immediately.

Comment: It's too early to look for solutions. You need to diagnose the problem first.

Comment: @user2858981: Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx): "*The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that has other handles open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file (FILE_SHARE_DELETE must have been specified when other handles were opened). The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed. Subsequent calls to CreateFile to open the file fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.*"

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: maybe something more like this: `while not DeleteFile(someFile) do begin case GetLastError() of ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Break; ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION: Sleep(500); else RaiseLastOSError; end; end;`